# How do I vertically and horizontally center text in a container in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Let's say I want to center the h1 and p elements in the division.

```
<div id="outer" class="container">
 <div id="inner">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Some content</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is very easy makes the parent div as `display: flex` and make the child element `margin: auto;`

Check the demo below.

```css
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

#inner {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer" class="container">
  <div id="inner">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="outer" class="container text-center">
<div id="inner">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
</div>

#outer{
min-height:100vh;
display:flex;
}

#inner{
margin:auto;
}
```

Please update your code as above. For `#outer` use `display:flex` & `min-height:100vh` which will span 100% of screen. For `#inner` use `margin:auto` to centered the text

Comment: Thank you. This did the job!

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 use flexbox, so `d-flex` assign the property `display: flex` than `align-items-center` aligns it vertically and  `justify-content-center` aligns it horizontally.

```
<div id="outer" class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div id="inner">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, some explanation of your answer would help others understand what you have done and why you have done it.

Comment: This imo is the best answer - just uses classes instead of custom css.